# Django Debug Toolbar Time Panel doesn't work

Tags: python, django, time, django-debug-toolbar

I have installed Django Debug Toolbar. All other panels work very well but the Time Panel.

There is Time Panel showed there, but when I click there is no response. When I click all other panels, it can display the related information such as sql panel, version panel etc.
How can get the Time Panel work, BTW, for my site, the SQL panel show only 3 to 4 seconds, but the Time panel show around 10 seconds, what is the diff, where is the 6 seconds?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

On Windows only the total time is available so there's no full size panel.

From [debug_toolbar/panels/timer.py](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/blob/bfd7652354a397c59a091d67af2e84acdc14e439/debug_toolbar/panels/timer.py#L11):

```
try:
    import resource     # Not available on Win32 systems
except ImportError:
    resource = None

[...]

class TimerPanel(Panel):
    [...]
    has_content = resource is not None
```

Comment: Answer is still relevant in 2022. Saved me time on debugging and searchin, cheers.